# Input data into a table using DLookUp in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am using a Data entry continuous form to input data into a table named 'Order_History'. All fields successfully input their data into that table except for one. I have a text box that uses DLookUp to get the value from a combo box on that form and use it to select data in hopes of entering it into the table. The DLookUp is getting the data from a different table named 'Postcodes'. I assume that the reason the others work is because the control source is linked to columns in the table.

Is there a way I can link this text box (Drop_Number) to the specific column in my Order_History table while still using DLookUp to get the values?

My DLookUp code:

```
=DLookup("Drop_Number", "Postcodes", "Postcode = [Forms]![Order_Form]![Postcode_cb]")
```

Comment: Use the AfterUpdate event of the ComboBox, although given the scenario the form is set up as a Continuous Form might not allow you to do this.

Comment: @PaulFrancis What would I put in the AfterUpdate event? I assume the control source has to remain the same for the entry to work. I tried messing around with the 'Default Value' property in events and such but it skips the first data row and puts the values in the next generated row. Peculiar to say the least.

Comment: Continuous Form setup will mess things up very badly. Not the right way to go about for unbound data.